# group data by year and filter for all year

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, group-by

I have a df with trade data from 2006 to 2018 ('all_trade', 345344 rows).
I want to filter out the first quantile of trade value of each year (group by year, then apply a filter).

Tried

```
Library (dplyr) 
trade_3q <- all_trade %>% group_by(all_trade$Year) %>% filter(all_trade$log_trade > quantile(all_trade$log_trade, 0.25)
```

but get "Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
x Input `..1` must be of size 25874 or 1, not size 345344."
What am I getting wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for others to answer or help, it will be very helpful if you can provide a sample data. Based on your descriptions, I can only *guess* how your data looks like. You can try this:

```
# simulate a data set
set.seed(1234)
tb <- tibble(year = sample(2006:2018, 50, replace = TRUE),
             trade = runif(50, 50000, 1000000)) %>%
  mutate(log_trade = log(trade))

# compute the quantile
tb2 <- tb %>% 
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(q25 = quantile(log_trade, 0.25)) 

# join back and filter             
tb %>% left_join(tb2, by = "year") %>%
  filter(log_trade > q25)
```

Comment: Thank you nyk for the answer. 
I apologise for not having provided sample data, but you got it right. 
And your answer works well, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

quantile() returns the descriptive string too ie 25%.

You could try removing this by wrapping quantile() in as.numeric() or unname().

Also looks like you may need another close bracket at the end.